# Problema al ejecutar un .jar desarrollado en JDK 1.8 Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

tengo un proyecto desarrollado en con el JDK 1.8 de java en NetBeans, al momento de ejecutarlo desde NetBeans, no me da problema alguno, el problema esta cuando construyo el proyecto y lo ejecuto en otra pc, mi pregunta es. ¿Solamente necesito instalar java y ese JDK en la nueva pc o que se requiere para que pueda correr de manera correcta? Gracias

Comment: Hola. Por favor, sé más claro en la descripción del problema. ¿Por qué dices que tienes un problema? Sale alguna traza de error? Se comporta de forma inesperada? Tu PC está en llamas? Sin un ejemplo mínimo o algún tipo de detalle, nos estás poniendo a adivinar. Ve a [edit] tu pregunta y amplía la descripción del problema (cómo creas el JAR, cómo lo ejecutas, qué sucede) . No resumas los errores, cópialos y pégalos, ojalá como texto

Comment: Me pregunto si la etiqueta jdbc tiene sentido aquí. Si la aplicación hace uso de una base de datos, es posible que no puedas mover la aplicación tan fácilmente a otro PC

Answer (score -1):

Para correr el archivo JAR en otro equipo solo deberia ser necesario el JRE de java. Para que lo puedas correr puedes crear un archivo .bat y en el poner lo siguiente 
`java -jar C:\ruta\a\TuArchivo.jar`

Comment: Estás asumiendo que usa Windows